# birt rcp report designer 4.8 java 8 startup problem

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I'm trying to install birt rcp report designer 4.8.0(standalone) and use it with java 8 jvm
I modfied my  birt.ini file to point to java 1.8 but as soon as I start I get a crash log

**birt.ini**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200
-vmargs
--Xms1024m -Xmx2048m  -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

**crash.log**

```
!SESSION 2021-10-13 19:34:40.154 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_202
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-10-13 19:34:40.701
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.rcp.DesignerApplication" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.ReportExecutor, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.nativePackageExtractor, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
```

I've tried googling it ,all that came up with is some old bug reports and suggestions of reinstalling java .i'm wondering what's gooing wrong since it seems like birt already picked up jvm as seen by the version number at the top of  stacktrace. Any ideas?

MY OS is win10 x 64 java is also x64

Answer (score 0):

`--Xms1024m` is not a valid VM argument because of the extra `-`. All of the VM arguments need to be on their own lines as well, so separate `-Xmx2048m` and `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work I tried removing   -vmargs
--Xms1024m -Xmx2048m  -XX:+DisableExplicitGC  and it still produced the same crash.log

Comment: How exactly did you install BIRT?

Comment: went to https://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-4.8.0-201806261756/birt-rcp-report-designer-4.8.0-20180626-win32.win32.x86_64.zip downloaded it  unzipped it, changed birt ini, ran birt.exe

Comment: Wait, so the .ini file has a `-vmargs` on the last line?